# What is the benefit of the database's information_schema for a hacker?

Tags: sql-injection, databases

What is the benefit of the database's information_schema for a hacker? I am talking about SQL injection exploitation.

Answer (score 1):

He can map which tables are in database as well their columns

Comment: And it might directly expose sensitive informations if the Schema allows access to running/cached queries, query plans or even values from columns by the way of histogram statistics. (But that is not directly related to injection)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you found an SQLi vulenrability that lets you run any SQL query you want, and see the full result. Great! But what do you run? If you don´t know the names of any tables or columns, you will have to guess them to get anywhere. And if the table you are looking for is not called `users` and the column is not called `password`, that may take a while.

This is where the [information schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema) comes to the rescue. It contains the name of all tables, columns, and such in the database, so you know what to query.

Comment: If information schema contains the name of everything in the database, Where can I find users and password in information schema?

Comment: It depens from database to database, you have to dig it out of information_schema

Comment: If you are talking about passwords stored _in_ the database, not the passwords used for _accessing_ the database. That's a different story: some may be in the system database (`mysql`, `master` etc.), but the logins may also be entirely external (`/etc/shadow`, Active Directory etc.). Good thing about all these is that they are encrypted & well protected, unlike the passwords users [may store](https://www.viestintavirasto.fi/en/cybersecurity/alerts/2018/varoitus-2018-02.html) in their databases.

Answer (score 1):

The attacker may only have a little peekhole to the database server via the SQL injection vulnerability: he may not be able to dump whole databases or tables, and it's possible that only certain types of queries can get through, at a limited rate. The information schema is the best shortcut to estimate what's the data he should be trying to get first and where exactly is it stored.